# PLSQL SOAP WebService

Tags: oracle, web-services, soap, plsql, envelope

I am trying to consume a SOAP web service request from PL/SQL.
On using the same envelope in SoapUI, it's successful.

Here's the code:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WEBSERVICE_CALL AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS

  req utl_http.req;
  RESP UTL_HTTP.RESP;
  value VARCHAR2(1024);
  P_DATA_TYPE VARCHAR2(6000):= 'application/soap+xml;';
  p_data_in VARCHAR2(6000) := '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://www.oracle.com/retail/sim/integration/services/StoreFulfillmentOrderService/v1" xmlns:v11="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/FulfilOrdColDesc/v1" xmlns:v12="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/FulfilOrdDesc/v1" xmlns:v13="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/FulfilOrdCustDesc/v1" xmlns:v14="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/LocOfFulfilOrdCustDesc/v1" xmlns:v15="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/localization/bo/BrFulfilOrdCustDesc/v1" xmlns:v16="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/custom/bo/EOfBrFulfilOrdCustDesc/v1" xmlns:v17="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/FulfilOrdDtl/v1">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v18:createFulfilOrdColDesc xmlns:v18="http://www.oracle.com/retail/rms/integration/services/FulfillOrderService/v1">
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v11:FulfilOrdColDesc>
            <v11:collection_size>1</v11:collection_size>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <v12:FulfilOrdDesc>
               <v12:customer_order_no>SA00469775001</v12:customer_order_no>
               <v12:fulfill_order_no>1</v12:fulfill_order_no>

               <v12:fulfill_loc_type>S</v12:fulfill_loc_type>
               <v12:fulfill_loc_id>19010</v12:fulfill_loc_id>
               <v12:partial_delivery_ind>Y</v12:partial_delivery_ind>
                       <!--Optional:-->
               <v12:delivery_type>C</v12:delivery_type>

               <v12:consumer_delivery_date>2015-03-30T05:48:37+05:30</v12:consumer_delivery_date>

               <!--Optional:-->
               <v12:comments>Transfer Testing</v12:comments>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <v13:FulfilOrdCustDesc>                  
                   <!--Optional:-->
                  <v13:deliver_first_name>Waqas</v13:deliver_first_name>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v13:deliver_last_name>Saeed</v13:deliver_last_name>

                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v13:deliver_add1>eXtra Main Building, IT Department</v13:deliver_add1>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v13:deliver_county>Saudi Arabia</v13:deliver_county>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v13:deliver_city>AL Bahah</v13:deliver_city>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v13:deliver_state>01</v13:deliver_state>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v13:deliver_country_id>SA</v13:deliver_country_id>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v13:deliver_phone>00966506406381</v13:deliver_phone>

                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v13:bill_first_name>Muhammad</v13:bill_first_name>

                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v13:bill_last_name>Makhaly</v13:bill_last_name>

                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v13:bill_add1>eXtra Main Building, IT Department</v13:bill_add1>

                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v13:bill_county>Saudi Arabia</v13:bill_county>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v13:bill_city>JEDDAH</v13:bill_city>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v13:bill_state>01</v13:bill_state>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v13:bill_country_id>SA</v13:bill_country_id>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v13:bill_phone>00966581156699</v13:bill_phone>
                  <!--Optional:-->

               </v13:FulfilOrdCustDesc>
               <!--1 or more repetitions:-->              
                   <v17:FulfilOrdDtl>
                  <v17:item>00166517</v17:item>                 
                  <v17:order_qty_suom>1.00</v17:order_qty_suom>
                  <v17:standard_uom>EA</v17:standard_uom>
                  <v17:transaction_uom>EA</v17:transaction_uom>
                  <v17:substitute_ind>N</v17:substitute_ind>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v17:unit_retail>799.00</v17:unit_retail>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v17:retail_curr>SAR</v17:retail_curr>
               </v17:FulfilOrdDtl>              
            </v12:FulfilOrdDesc>

         </v11:FulfilOrdColDesc>
      </v18:createFulfilOrdColDesc>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

  BEGIN

  REQ := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST('http://exvm-cnvrmsapp01.extrastores.com:7118/FulfillOrderBean/FulfillOrderService?WSDL', 'POST');
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'SOAPAction', '');
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-type', p_data_type);
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-length', length(p_data_in));
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
  utl_http.write_text(req, p_data_in);
  resp := utl_http.get_response(req);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('status code: ' || RESP .STATUS_CODE);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('reason phrase: ' || RESP .REASON_PHRASE);

  LOOP
  utl_http.read_line(resp, value, TRUE);
  dbms_output.put_line(value);
  END LOOP;
  utl_http.end_response(resp);
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN utl_http.end_of_body THEN
  UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(RESP);
  END;
```

On executing the above procedure, I get the following error:
status code: 415
reason phrase: Unsupported Media Type

What could be wrong in here?j

Comment: Problem is in webservice server. It probably does not accept "application/soap+xml". Is it a SOAP web service?

Comment: Yes, it's a soap web service.
What else could I replace it with ?

Comment: sometimes web service accepts only "text/xml". Problem can be also in message header. it omits `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, see [http://scn.sap.com/thread/1880999](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1880999)

Comment: Verified from the SoapUI head that it was text/xml. 
But it still gives the same error. 

where should the encoding part be added in the Envelope?

Comment: At the start of you p_data string. it shoul start `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http...`

Comment: Added that, but the issue remains same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mismatch between between client and server - Soap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938472/mismatch-between-between-client-and-server-soap)